# A 5 digit number is formed using the digits 0,1,2,3,4 and 5, probability it is divisible by 6?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, divisibility, factorial

> A $5$ digit number is formed by using the digits $0,1,2,3,4$ and $5$ without
>   repetition. The probability that the number is divisible by $6$ is?

**Answer** : 18%

I had doubts regarding this question but while writing my attempt here, I got the solution. So, I am posting it as an answer.

Comment: I just got it. In case 1, for divisibility by 2, the last number can be chosen in 3 ways(0,2,4)

Comment: Yes, also if $0$ is chosen for the last digit, the remaining digits can be permuted $4!$ ways.

Answer (score 5):

> Total $5$ digit numbers formed by the given digits=$5*5!=600$
>
> > For divisibility by 6, the numbers must be divisible by both 2 and 3.
> >
> > Only numbers formed by digits **(i) (0,1,2,4,5)** and **(ii)
> >     (1,2,3,4,5)** are divisible by 3.
> >
> > (i)  **CASE 1: ( 0,1,2,4,5)**   For divisibility by 2, _ _ _ _ _
> >
> > (a) if 0 is placed at the end, then number of ways=4!=24   (b) if 0 is not placed in the end, then there are two ways to select the last
> >     digit(2,4). Number of ways=$2C1*3C1*3!=36$
> >     For this case, total number of ways=24+36=60
> >
> > (ii) **CASE 2: ( 1,2,3,4,5)**    Again, the last number can be chosen in $2C1$ ways and the
> >     remaining 4 numbers can permute in $4!$ ways. The required number of
> >     ways for this case= $2*4!= 48$
> >
> > Adding the number of ways in the two cases, 5 digit numbers that are
> >     divisible by 6= 108
> >
> > Required Probability = $\frac{108}{600} = $0.18$= $18%